# How to push object in an array?

Tags: jquery

I have an Array name is dataObj. dataObj array have some objects but after click on checkbox, dataObj array should be blank and getting new objects.

```
Any mistake in below code. Thanks for your help
var dataObj = [];
var copyDataObj = [];
dataObj = <?php echo json_encode($travellerDetails); ?>
copyDataObj = dataObj;
$('.checkbox_check').click(function() {
    var checkbox_values = [];//all the checked value in this array
    $("input[name='airlines']:checked").each( function () {
        checkbox_values.push($(this).val());
    });
    dataObj = [];
    for(var i=0;i<=checkbox_values.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<=copyDataObj.length;j++){
            if(copyDataObj[j].operator1 == checkbox_values[i]){
                dataObj.push(copyDataObj[j]);//here is the problem
            }
        }
    }
    displayResult();
});
```

> copyDataObj[j] = Object {
>           trip_id: "3", 
>           booking_reference: "test123",
>           flight: "3", 
>           flight2: "0", 
>           dep_date: "2016-12-30"
>           ...
>       }

My question is how to push `copyDataObj[j]` object in `dataObj` Array?

Comment: You've defined `dataObj` as a string, not an array. Use `var dataObj = [];`

Comment: dataObject is not an Array

Comment: dataObj is an Array. I defined it above in code but i did not write here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by defining dataObj as an array *var dataObj = [];*, but when you clear it in the click function, you set it to a string: *dataObj = " ";*. Should be *var dataObj = [];* again.

Comment: var dataObj = [];
var copyDataObj = [];
dataObj = <?php echo json_encode($travellerDetails); ?>
copyDataObj = dataObj;

Comment: Any mistake in below code. Thanks for your help.                                   var dataObj = [];
var copyDataObj = [];
dataObj = <?php echo json_encode($travellerDetails); ?>
copyDataObj = dataObj;

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `dataObj` as an array [`[]`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) instead of a string. Then you will be able to push objects into it:

```
var dataObj = [];
dataObj.push(copyDataObj[j]);
```

Comment: dataObj is an Array. I defined it above in code but i did not write here.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `dataObj` as a string. It must be an array to be able to push items into it.

`dataObj = []`

Comment: dataObj is an Array. I defined it above in code but i did not write here.